# Custom Field Populating

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I have a custom field that I am trying to figure out how it is being populated. It doesn't have a formula in the custom field settings. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

You can Developer Console to find out the references of your custom field in Apex Triggers and Classes.

`Step to make search:
1. Open Developer Console
2. In Edit tab choose Search In Files (Ctrl + Shift + H)
3. Search your custom field. you will get all references where your field is used in Code.`

You also need to check references in Workflows.

Comment: Further to this, this app enables relatively easier way of searching through workflow rules: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI. You can also an IDE like Welkin Suite, BrainEngine or Eclipse to search through workflows too. Workflows can be added as a metadata component to the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer : DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION SYSTEM.**

A shabby way is to delete the field in your SANDBOX, if the field is referenced in a trigger/ class or workflow you will get a deletion failure and list of metadata where the field is used.